# Tag created by single user with no request from authors

Tags: discussion, tags, suggested-edits

[dtn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dtn) has been created just now by suggested edits by a single user.  None of the question or answer authors seem to have thought such a tag was necessary.  And at least one of the questions is just a C++ language issue; the networking aspects are completely immaterial.

Is it appropriate for a user to go tagging like this?  Do we need some indicator in the suggested edit queue that a tag is brand new, with few if any other questions and no wiki?

Comment: And now [a question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20688914/103167) where I can't see any connection to the new tag at all.  Both use the term "bundle", but that's hardly a unique concept.

Comment: Where the question authors requested the tag or not isn't really relevant.  If the tag is appropriate, then edits are fine.  If not, then they aren't.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Note that the user made six tag-only *suggested* edits in just over 20 minutes, ignoring other issues in the posts.

Comment: @psubsee2003: Don't you think the review process should be different for addition of a tag with very few uses?  Among other things, it suggests that there might be an existing appropriate tag with different declension or abbreviation.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot whether these specific suggested edits were good edits or not wasn't really part of my comment.  I was responding to the "...with no request from authors" portion of this discussion.  Whether or not the OP of the question asked for the tag is entirely not relevant.  If the tag relevant to the question, the a suggested edit to add the tag is prefectly acceptable (while fixing the other issues).

Comment: @BenVoigt Not necessarily.  Generally a tag with no wiki that is not obvious of the use is a horrible tag.  The fact that the user had to explain the acronym in the edit description says a lot.  I don't think a low use tag needs special consideration. Good, relevant tags are needed.  Crappy tags aren't needed.  Plus there are already users who watch for newly created tags.  The biggest issue I see here is the reviewers who approved these edits because I'll bet that most had no idea what `dtn` was and how it applied to the question.

Comment: @psubsee2003: But a tag is useful only if someone wants it, right?  Everything you say makes sense for putting an existing tag on questions, but not for creation of a new tag.

Comment: And before we can discipline the reviewers, we need consensus on whether the edits are poor.

Comment: @BenVoigt there are dozens of discussions on the appropriateness of tag-only edits.  I fail to see why a newly created tag makes the discussion any different.

Comment: @psubsee2003: I see "Creation of a new tag" as a different action from "Putting a question into an existing category".  In the latter, only whether the tag applies needs to be considered.  In the former, whether or not the tag represents a useful and needed category also needs to be considered.

Comment: @BenVoigt I still don't see the distinction.  A bad tag is a bad tag regardless of the number of posts or the age.  But if you feel adding a new tag is less appropriate then then adding an existing tag, then maybe the discussion needs to be about user privileges and whether the 1500 rep limit for new tags is appropriate.